# My wifi working slow on Ubuntu and fast on other devices

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, internet, router

I have been using my wifi for over a month now and have not encountered any problem. Recently after a long time I went back to my Ubuntu 20.04 and went to update the kernel. What I instantly noticed that my internet speed was extremely slow. For cross checking, I checked my mobile device for the same and speeds were normally fast.
The crazy part is that when I connected Ubuntu with my phone's data connection, the speeds were normal. So it seems that the problem is with my wifi broadband connection on ubuntu .
Can anyone please suggest a possible fix.
I tried following:-

1. Disbling wifi powersave
2. Stopping ipv6 use.
3. Preventing 802.11
   None of the above worked for me.

Output for lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:08a6]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.